# Python build error "ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly"

Tags: python, docker

I'm trying to build python in Docker but when I run docker build it says

```
#6 136.7 Failed to build numpy
#6 136.7 ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I already tried upgrading my pip but it is still the same.

My Python version is 3.8.4

Comment: is this FULL error message? `Numpy` uses C/C++ code and it may need compiler C/C++ for this. And full error message should show more information about problem. And upgrading `pip` can't help with this.

Comment: I think this problem was few times on Stackoverflow and you may find some answers for this. BTW: in right column I see `Related` and there are similir question with `PEP 517` for different modules but they may show some idea how to resolve it also for `numpy`.

Comment: BTW: it may need also to install some C/C++ libraries - or at least some C/C++ headers. If you use docker with `Ubuntu` then it would need to use program `apt` to install some packages with suffix `-dev` (for `develop`) - ie. `apt install python3.8-dev`

Comment: Thanks for the advices, @furas. I found the issue, the version in my requirements.txt of numpy is not updated.